# Orbits of symplectic group $Sp(2n,K)$ acting on $K^{2n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Let $J_n$ be a matrix of standard non-degenerate symplectic form

$$J_n=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

With coeffitients in the field $K$. I define the symplectic group to be
$$Sp(2n,K)=\{A\in GL_{2n}(K) \ | \ A^TJ_nA=J_n\}$$
This group acts on vector space $K^{2n}$ by standard multiplication of matrix by vector $A \cdot v$

Question is to show that $Sp(2n,K)$ has 2 orbits: $K^{2n}\setminus\{0\}$ and $\{0\}$.

I tried to construct a matrix $A\in Sp(2n,K)$ that transforms vector $e_1=(1, 0, \cdots , 0)$ to nonzero vector $v=(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_{2n})$ but managed to do it only for the case $n=1$. How do I prove this for any $n$?

Comment: Hii, welcome to MSE. What have you tried so far? Please edit your question and provide context. Show us your working, on what step you got stuck and need help, your thoughts about the problem etc. Have a look at [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) text to know how to ask a good question here.

Comment: Hello, I edited my question and I think everything is clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not really explained your context, but as a raw linear algebra question this is not immediate or trivial. For broader context, this is a very special case of Witt's theorem about extension of isometries from subspaces to the whole space, in non-degenerate alternating(symplectic), quadratic, and unitary spaces. The alternating/symplectic case is somewhat easier.

In any case, a too matrix-bound approach may have more baggage than we'd desire...

In your somewhat-more-limited case, an induction on the dimension can succeed. Given a vector $f_{2n}$, the non-degeneracy promises a vector $f_{2n-1}$ so that $\langle f_{2n-1},f_{2n}\rangle=1$. The "orthogonal complement" $W=\{v:\langle v,f_{2n-1}\rangle=\langle v,f_{2n}\rangle=0\}$ is a non-degenerate alternating space. By induction on $n$ (and, as you've done, the $n=1$ case can be done very explicitly), the automorphism group of that smaller orthogonal group is transitive on non-zero vectors...

There are various ways of composing the remainder of the argument, but the existence of the complementary vector $f_{2n-1}$ is a key...